# jupyter notebook with python and sklearn. precision score error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

1. This is the code below for jupyter noetbook with python and sklearn function (precision score).wnat to get the score by using t_test & y_test and got this error...
   "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous-multioutput and binary targets"
2. list item code:

   ```
   diabetes = pd.read_csv("datasets/diabetes.csv")
   x = diabetes.drop(diabetes.columns[-1], axis=1)
   y = diabetes.iloc[:,-1]
   scaler = StandardScaler()
   scaler.fit_transform(x)
   svc = SVC()
   x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, 
                                                       random_state = RANDOM_STATE)
   svc.fit(x_train,y_train)
   precision_score_svc = precision_score(x_test, y_test)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html):

```
sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y_true, y_pred, *, labels=None, pos_label=1, average='binary', sample_weight=None, zero_division='warn')

[...]

Parameters
y_true 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix
Ground truth (correct) target values.

y_pred 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix
Estimated targets as returned by a classifier.
```

Means you need to provide the true labels followed by predicted labels. It should be:

```
precision_score_svc = precision_score(y_test,svc.predict(x_test))
```

Comment: thanx man u r the best. its helps . thanx again its very kind of u